# Match and Replace any text inside parenthesis providing a given word is inside

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove everything inside a parenthesis or brackets providing there is a certain word inside, for example;

```
Test String (Foo Bar)
```

I have my regex pattern like this:

```
r'\s(\(|\[)(.*?)Bar(\)|\])'
```

Which results in

```
Test String
```

But if I have text like:

```
Test String (Foo Bar)
Test String (Bar)
```

and I want the results to both be

```
Test String
Test String
```

I would need a separate regex call? or can I configure the regex to handle both at the same time?

Comment: You probably want `\s*[([][^][]*Bar[^][]*[])]`, see https://regex101.com/r/bZX0wF/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that matches `Test String (Foo Bar]`, which I assume is not wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replaces matches of the regular expression

```
r'\s+(?:\([^)\r\n]*Bar[^)\r\n]*\)|\[[^]\r\n]*Bar[^]\r\n]*\])'
```

with empty strings.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6LpuK8/3/)

[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/ZRdokesH)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\s+          match 1+ spaces
(?:          begin non-capture group
  \(         match "("
  [^)\r\n]*  match 0+ chars other than ")", "\r" or "\n"
  Bar        match "Bar"
  [^)\r\n]*  match 0+ chars other than ")", "\r" or "\n"
  \)         match ")"
  |          or
  \[         match "["
  [^]\r\n]*  match 0+ chars other than "]", "\r" or "\n"
  Bar        match "Bar"
  [^]\r\n]*  match 0+ chars other than "]", "\r" or "\n"
  \]         match "]"
)            end non-capture group
```

Comment: Is \r\n necessary? Doesn't \s match all whitespace characters including the windows carriage return

Comment: @dumbPy, yes, but I am not excluding `\s` in those character classes.